# Trying to trace Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I can't trace, the error is:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
Private Sub UpdateLV(ByVal  id As String)

    Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE tbl_sharePay SET Old_code= '" & ComboBox6.Text & "' ,Chapa= '" & TextBox2.Text & "' , Fname= '" & TextBox3.Text & "', Lname= '" & TextBox4.Text & "', Spgroup= '" & TextBox6.Text & "', Sharecap= '" & TextBox7.Text & "', PrevSP= '" & TextBox8.Text & "', CurSP= '" & TextBox9.Text & "', Rec= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' , SpYear= '" & TextBox11.Text & "', Spstatus= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' WHERE Old_code=" & id & ""
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql

    If (adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
        cleartextboxes()
        MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
    End If

    con.Close()
    Retrieve()

    If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Close()
    End If

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.  Somewhere in your Update statement you're trying to use a variable of a type that doesn't match the field types of tbl_sharePay.  Use Sql Parameters and among other benefits, this problem close to simply goes away.

Comment: And please read the description of the tags you've added to your question and remove the unnecessary ones

Comment: I can't see a try to match the end try either.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue - AN issue, at least - should be fairly obvious. The error message is telling you that there's an issue with data types so you should have checked the data type of every column and every value in that SQL code. You clearly haven't done so.

You have the `Old_code` column specified in both the `SET` clause and the `WHERE` clause but you have the value wrapped in single quotes in one place, indicating that the value is a string, and not in the other, indicating that the value is likely a number. Obviously they can't both be correct. You need to determine what data type that column is and use data of that type in both locations in your SQL code. There's no way for us to tell but there's every chance that you're doing something similar with one or more of the other columns too.

As suggested in the comments, if you wrote proper ADO.NET code and used parameters rather than string concatenation, issues like this just go away. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) and modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your connection in the method where it is used. Connections need to be disposed in addition to closed. Using...End Using blocks are used to accomplish this. You should not need to check the connection state since it is created locally.

Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. OleDb does not match up parameter names. It is positional. The order that the parameters appear in the CommandText must match the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection. You will need to carefully check your database for the OleDbTypes and correct the code accordingly. If any of the values assigned to the parameters need to be numbers then be sure to do the conversion so the correct type is sent to the database.

Don't open the connection until directly before the Execute....

You don't need a DataAdapter. Just excute your command. When you do use a DataAdapter it will open and close the connection for you. The constructor (New) use a Select command not an Update command.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Id As Integer = 7 'Whatever value
    Dim RecordsUpdated As Integer
    Try
        RecordsUpdated = UpdateLV(Id)
        If RecordsUpdated = 1 Then
            cleartextboxes()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated")
            Retrieve()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Update Failed")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function UpdateLV(ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
    Dim RecordsAffected As Integer
    Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE tbl_sharePay 
                        SET Old_code= @OldCode, 
                        Chapa= @Chapa, 
                        Fname= @Fname, 
                        Lname= @Lname, 
                        Spgroup= @Sp,   
                        Sharecap= @Share, 
                        PrevSP= @PrevSP, 
                        CurSP= @CursP, 
                        Rec= @Rec, 
                        SpYear= @Year, 
                        Spstatus= @Status 
                        WHERE Old_code= @ID;"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string."),
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@OldCode", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(ComboBox6.Text)
            .Add("@Chapa", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@Fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
            .Add("@Lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
            .Add("@Sp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
            .Add("@Share", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text
            .Add("@PrevSP", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text
            .Add("@CursP", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text
            .Add("@Rec", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            .Add("@Year", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text
            .Add("@Status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id
        End With
        con.Open()
        RecordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RecordsAffected
End Function
```